# FirebaseFirestore: How can I know if the request is done or it's in standby?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, request

When I request to submit a request like this :

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('col1')
            .doc("ID1")
            .collection("col2")
            .add({
          'info1': info1,
          'info2': info2,
          'info3': info2,
          'info4': [info1,info1],
```

and display it in another place by this request :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('col1')
          .doc("ID1")
          .collection("col2")
          .orderBy("CreateAt", descending: true);
```

It will be displayed even if the device are not connected to the internet (for example),
so how can I know for every document that the document is sent to the database or not ?
I'm using flutter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know whether your write operation completed on the server, you can add a completion listener to the [`add` call](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) by waiting for the returned `Future` to resolve.

If you want to know if a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) contains any data that may not have been written to the server yet, check its `metadata.hasPendingWrites` property.